# How would you optimize the search for newborn and toggle it

Tags: angularjs

Having this code.  I am not sure if there is an easier way to do the same thing

```js
$scope.parent = {
  id: 1,
  name: kev,
  children: [{
    id: 1,
    firstborn: true
  }, {
    id: 2,
    firstborn: false
  }, {
    id: 3,
    firstborn: false
  }]
};

$scope.toggleFirstBorn = function(parent, child) {
  //toggle firstborn          
  angular.forEach(parent.children, function(child) {
    ea.firstborn = false;
  });

  child.firstborn = true;

};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-repeat="child in parent.children">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" ng-class="{true:'active, btn-success', false: ''}[child.firstborn == 1]"  ng-click="toggleFirstBorn(parent,child)">Is FirstBorn</button>
        </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you do not have to repeat `firstChild` property on each child object. Instead use associated property. `firstChild` is a relative property of a child with its parent. So you could add a property on the parent `firstChild` which will have the id of the child.

If you don't want to access any other properties on the child then as good as setting the appropriate child id in the first child property:

```
$scope.parent = {
    id: 1,
    name: "Name1",
    children: [{
      id: 1

    }, {
      id: 2

    }, {
      id: 3
    }],
    firstChild: 1
  };


  $scope.toggleFirstBorn = function(parent, child) {
    $scope.parent.firstChild = child.id;

  };

  $scope.isFirst = function(parent, child) {
    return angular.equals(parent.firstChild, child.id);
    //you could just compare this in the view itself.
    //"{true:'active btn-success', false: ''}[parent.firstChild === child.id)]"
  }
```

If you want to access entire child object for some reason then add a property that holds the object itself based on id.

```
 $scope.parent = {
    id: 1,
    name: "Name1",
    children: [{
      id: 1

    }, {
      id: 2

    }, {
      id: 3
    }],
    firstChild: 1
  };

  //Set the initial data, keep firstChildOb as property that holds the reference. 
  //You can use a variable as well if you do not have a collection of parents and their children.
  //using array.some here you could as well use for loop and set the property
  $scope.parent.children.some(function(child) {
    return (child.id === $scope.parent.firstChild) && ($scope.parent.firstChildOb = child);
  });

  //On toggle just replace the object reference
  $scope.toggleFirstBorn = function(parent, child) {
     parent.firstChildOb = child;
   };

  //comparator that compares the current child with already set firstChildObj
  $scope.isFirst = function(parent, child) {
    return angular.equals(parent.firstChildOb, child);
  }
```

and

```
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" 
         ng-class="{true:'active btn-success', false: ''}[isFirst(parent,child)]"  
         ng-click="toggleFirstBorn(parent,child)">Is FirstBorn</button>
```

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.parent = {
    id: 1,
    name: "Name1",
    children: [{
      id: 1

    }, {
      id: 2

    }, {
      id: 3
    }],
    firstChild: 1
  };

  //Set the initial data
  $scope.parent.children.some(function(child) {
    return (child.id === $scope.parent.firstChild) && ($scope.parent.firstChildOb = child);
  });

 //or with array.find
 /*$scope.parent.firstChildOb = $scope.parent.children.find(function(child){ child.id ===  $scope.parent.firstChild});*/

  $scope.toggleFirstBorn = function(parent, child) {
    $scope.parent.firstChildOb = child;

  };

  $scope.isFirst = function(parent, child) {
    return angular.equals(parent.firstChildOb, child);
  }

});
```

```css
.active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="child in parent.children">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary" ng-class="{true:'active btn-success', false: ''}[isFirst(parent,child)]"  ng-click="toggleFirstBorn(parent,child)">Is FirstBorn</button>
        </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Polyfill for Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

[Polyfill for Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to introduce several ways of solving the problem. I agree that the parent.firstChild="childid" is a better approach. I changed my data structure to implement that approach.   It's also helpful to know about the .some function.